# Redirecting $_SESSION['username']

Tags: php, session

I have 3 different users of my site and I'm trying to set page restrictions for certain users with..

on **pcheck.php** :

```
if (!$_SESSION['username']=='player')
     header("Location: error.php");
```

Then I included it on all pages where only the user (player) can access :

```
include("pcheck.php");
```

However, even when I log as player user I am still being redirected to **error.php**

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I have tried putting **session_start();** at the beginning of *pcheck.php* but I am also able to access the page with a different user and that is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: `if (!$_SESSION['username']=='player')` to `if ($_SESSION['username']!='player')`

Comment: !== just to be safe: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: change      `header("Location: error.php");` to `     header("Location:error.php");` just delete the space and try again

Comment: and please first delete the redirect line and echo `$_SESSION['username']` and see if it player or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the `!` in the wrong spot.  You want:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] !== 'player')
```

Your code was being interpreted as:

```
if ((!$_SESSION['username']) == 'player')
```

Comment: It worked! Though I still needed to put session_start() on pcheck.php. Cheers!